# How can I find current device position?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

Using Unity AR fondation 4.x and AR Core how can i find the current device position?

I have been monitoring the device camera position inside the AR Session Origin object but it seems buggy and unfiltered, is there a method that gives me the filtered position of the device?

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I use `FirstPersonCamera.transform.position` to get x,y,z coordinates of the device and it works well.